# Using functions in a namespace that hasn't been declared from template

Tags: c++

The following code give me an error that `'print2' is not a member of 'N'` when using both clang and gcc:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Printer
{
    template<class T>
    void print(T t)
    {
        N::print2(*this, t);
    }
};

namespace N
{
    void print2(Printer& p, int v)
    {
        printf("%d\n", v);
    }
}

int main()
{
    Printer p;
    p.print(1);
}
```

If I remove the namespace N and make the `print2` function global it works. Why is the lookup different when the function is put in a namespace and when it's not? Unfortunately I can't move the `print2` function before `struct Printer`, which would've been the obvious solution.

Comment: Complains about `print` NOT `print2` live: https://godbolt.org/z/6wi2YK   Please check.edit the question.

Comment: It will complain about `print2` though: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a587c9bd14cadcbf

Comment: *Unfortunately I can't move the print2 function before struct Printer* Why not?  Can you not at least forward declare it?  Like all cases, a name must be at least declared before you can use it.

Comment: [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5a446b1688952a0) is the same error with the function in the global namespace. You either have a weird compiler, or you didn't compile the code you thought you compiled.

Comment: @NathanOliver [Technically](https://xkcd.com/1475/) one could argue that dependent names in two-phase lookup can be "used" (in a template definition) before they are declared (between the template definition and the template instantiation).

Comment: I apparently removed a bit too much code before posting. I've updated the snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Here I am simply declaring the function before Printer, while defining the logic of the function afterwards.

```
#include <stdio.h>

namespace N {
    void print2(int);
}

struct Printer
{
    template<class T>
    void print(T t)
    {
        N::print2(t);
    }
};

namespace N
{
    void print2(int v)
    {
        printf("%d\n", v);
    }
}

int main()
{
    Printer p;
    p.print(1);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's something I really like to avoid for various reasons that have nothing to do with the code really.